# How to start wiremock standalone with custom hostname?

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

For example, I want to start wiremock standalone with hostname "my.abc.com" with port 9999. Where can I config that? Or what is the right command line options for hostname?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The hostname is determined by DNS or your host file, rather than WireMock itself.

If you want to run everything locally but with a hostname other than `localhost` you can edit your hosts file and add a line like:

```
127.0.0.1 api.mydomain.com
```

Then you can hit a locally running WireMock server on e.g. http://api.mydomain.com:9999/

As agoff points out, if you want to use the Java DSL against the instance you need to configure it:

```java
WireMock.configureFor("api.mydomain.com", 9999);
```

The host file can be found in the following places:
Windows - `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

Mac - `/private/etc/hosts`

*nix - `/etc/hosts`