# How to configure WireMockServer host and port correctly?

Tags: wiremock

I am trying to mock an external service(my.domain.com:1234), which is called by **WebClient**. But I didn't figure out how to configure the host and port correctly. It seems only work with **localhost** and port: **8080**. What did I missed?

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer();
    configureFor("localhost", 8080);
    wireMockServer.start();
}
```

I wound be great if someone can show me a working code example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start wiremock standalone with custom hostname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75385279/how-to-start-wiremock-standalone-with-custom-hostname)